# ASP.NET TimeDate stamp on file gets overriden

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code here that take base 64 string and creates bytes, next I create a file name for these bytes.

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(landingCells.imageBytes);
var filePath = landingCells.jobNo + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff");
```

next I have save these bytes:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:/app/Images/" + filePath + ".jpg", bytes);
```

The problem I am having is I am calling these lines of code in a loop via an iOS app and sometimes the yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff is the same as the previous item in the loop. My question, how can I make the file names more unique so this does not happen.

Comment: Maybe use a GUID instead of a date stamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This by using Guid.NewGuid():

```
var uniquecode=Guid.NewGuid();
     var filePath = landingCells.jobNo + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff")+uniquecode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a date-based name will limit your file creation rate to the frequency of the system clock (and is also not threadsafe) which is why you are seeing duplicate file names when you complete iterations of your loop too quickly. You have several options to make it more unique that depend on what your requirements are:

- Add an incrementing counter suffix to the file name when the date is the same as the date of the last file written
- Incorporate a GUID into the file name. This will be less readable than the counter suffix but will guarantee uniqueness even across a distributed system and won't require you to maintain a counter.
- Incorporate some other original information about the file or its metadata into the name that when combined with the date will be unique
- Come up with some custom name generation algorithm that will generate unique names for every (even repeated) input. How you do this depends on the domain you're working within and the data you're dealing with.

I'm not sure what kind app you're building, but it's worth reevaluating whether you actually need to write that many images to disk per second and if you do whether a video would be better. Throttling the writes would probably not be a bad idea and it would also solve the naming problem.